# printf string with "%s" loss character after sort

Tags: c, printf, bubble-sort

This is a simple sorting code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    char str[] = "Hello!! How are you?? I'm Fine. No Thank you.", temp;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < sizeof(str); j++) {
            if (str[i] > str[j]) {
                temp = str[j];
                str[j] = str[i];
                str[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(str); i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

I found out that I'm able to print the sorted string character by character through `for` loop but not `printf("%s", str);`, it wouldn't print anything, can someone tell me why and how to solve this?

Comment: Because your first character is obviously `\0`. Print `printf("%d %d\n", strlen(str), str[0]);`

Comment: Use `strlen(str)` instead of `sizeof(str)`. The latter includes the NUL and may include things like padding as well.

Comment: Also use `strlen` before the loop to read the length into a temporary variable.

Comment: You've sorted the characters of the string _inadvertently_ including the terminating NUL character.  That terminating NUL character has moved to the front of the character array making the array look like an empty string.  This is, as others have pointed out, because you counted characters with `sizeof(str)` which includes the terminating character, instead of `strlen(str)` which would have just counted the number of characters in the "string" interpretation of that char array.

Comment: understood, thankyou all!

Comment: `strlen()` not truly needed either. `i < sizeof(str)` --> `str[i] != 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compute the size of your string as `sizeof(str)`. That includes the trailing `\0`. The byte `\0` is guaranteed to end up at the beginning of your sorted string, telling `printf` that the string is actually empty. You want to leave the terminating NUL past the end of the string, since it is not part of the buffer that you want to sort.

To sort only the characters of the string, without the terminator, change the loop to

```
int n = strlen(str);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
```

Comment: The worst case you describe is not possible. Using `sizeof` on an array will give you exactly the number of elements times the size of each element - no padding.

Comment: Yes, the error that @sepp2k pointed out should be fixed so as not to be misleading in the accepted answert.

Comment: @sepp2k. Thanks. Updated

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE agreed and fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strlen` function to calculate length of string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    char str[] = "Hello!! How are you?? I'm Fine. No Thank you.", temp;

    int n = strlen(str);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(str[i]>str[j]){
                temp = str[j];
                str[j]=str[i];
                str[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%c",str[i]); 
    printf("%s", str);
}
```